# Multiple employee list not working in orangehrm

Tags: php, mysql, orangehrm

I am trying to add employees list in dropdown  in jobtitle section but i am getting only one name from dropdown.Here's my code

```
JobTitleForm.php
mysql_connect("xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxx");
        mysql_select_db("xxxxxx");
        $querydata=mysql_query("select * from hs_hr_employee");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($querydata))
         {
            $firstname=$row["emp_firstname"];
            $employeeid=$row["employee_id"];
            $employees = array($employeeid=>$firstname);
            $widgets['Reportingmanager'] = new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $employees));

         }

saveJobTitlesuccess.php
 <li class="largeTextBox">
                        <?php echo $form['Reportingmanager']->renderLabel(__('Reportingmanager')); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['Reportingmanager']->render(); ?>
                    </li>
```

Comment: you have to use `foreach`

Comment: should i use in viewpage foreach

Comment: yes.. you have to use there

Comment: how to use foreach for that?

Comment: you check number of results in table like this "echo mysql_num_rows($querydata); " . add this before while loop . its display number of records in the query

Comment: i want to print all empoyees in dropdown in view page

Comment: This code is positively archaic. See the 21st century